# Save image in folder and retrieve image url in Ktor Web API

Tags: ktor

I uploaded image and store it in specific folder, and it's working, but I want the images back as image_url, there is no way found in Ktor Web API.

Please help me if anyone has a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to serve an uploaded image by a specific URL?

Comment: yes like http://name.domain/folder_name/image.jpg

Comment: Please share the code, how did you store image in specific folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you can [serve static files](https://ktor.io/docs/serving-static-content.html):

```
embeddedServer(Netty, port = 9999, host = "localhost") {
    routing {
        static("folder_name") { // web path
            files("folder_name") // folder from where to serve files
        }
    }
}.start(wait = true)
```

Also, you can have a specific route to respond with the contents of a specific image:

```
routing {
    get("/folder_name/image.jpg") {
        call.respondFile(File("./folder_name/image.jpg"))
    }
}
```